# How to implement an Observer-pattern with two packages

Tags: java, package, naming

A friend and I have a discussion of how to implement an observer pattern with two packages.

Here is a fictional example:
Package "Gaming" contains the class "Battlefield".
Package "Players" contains "IPlayer" (and various implementations of this interface).

Now we want the battlefield to observe the player. For this reason we create an interface "IPlayerObserver" and "IOberservablePlayer". IPlayer inherits IOberservablePlayer.

In which package should we put "IPlayerObserver"?

```
// Package: Players
public interface IPlayer extends IOberservablePlayer {}

// Package: Gaming
public class Battlefield implements IPlayerObserver {}

// Which package?
public interface IPlayerObserver {
     void notify(IPlayer player);
}

public interface IOberservablePlayer {
     void addObserver(IPlayerObserver observer);
}
```

Thanks for all answers in advantage.

Comment: your interface names are telling you: Players..

Comment: You would certainly notice if you make seperate modules out of _players_ and _gaming_. Now, if you add a third module that also wants to notify a player, you rather want to have a dependency on _player_ rather than _gaming_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    core
    ^  ^
    |  |
    | player
    |    ^
    |    |
    gaming
```

- Keep wholly `Player`-focused items with player
- Don't call a spade a spade. IEverything pattern harks back to [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and simply isn't needed these days. If your interface is the primary thing code will reference then give it the cleanest name.
- You can probably genericise the `Observable` interface as I have done below and put it in the common "core" package

```java
package com.yourname.player;
public interface Player extends Oberservable<PlayerObserver>

package com.yourname.gaming;
public class Battlefield implements PlayerObserver 

package com.yourname.player;
public interface PlayerObserver {
     void notify(Player player);
}

package com.yourname.core;
public interface Oberservable<T> {
     void addObserver(T observer);
}
```

Further, it is slightly cleaner not to implement such listeners directly on other important classes as it exposes methods like `Battlefield.notify(Player)` to everyone when only `Player` is meant to call it.

Try doing this inside `Battlefield`:

```
player.addObserver(this::playerNotification)
...
private void playerNotification(Player p) {}
```

Comment: you have spent waaaaay to much time on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ^_^   +1

Comment: Between jobs. Can't help myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like David Pérez stated in his comment: Your interface names are already telling you.
It makes sense to group everything that's required to observe players in one package, so that another package only needs to import the players package.